# Why Eclipse puts @Override annotation on implemented interface methods (and then it doesn't work in Maven)?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I wrote a simple project in Java in Eclipse. I just wanted to have a proof-of-concept. 
Then it became good enough to be refactored into a maven project so I created the maven project, I copied the sources and I re-imported the project in eclipse. But it was giving an error on every interface I implemented. This because there was the @Override annotation on the methods. But Eclipse generated it! Isn't it supposed to be good at suggesting things?

I removed everything. Then curiosly if now I implement an interface (like say Runnable) the Override annotation doesn't come out anymore (I mean using the cntrl+1 generation tool).

Why was that good when I created the project in Eclipse, then it was no more in the Maven project? Why Eclipse did stop adding the annotation in the Maven project?

Answer (score 3):

I found out by myself, so I'm writing it down just in case somebody needs it. I didn't notice that Eclipse set JDK compliance to 1.5 when Importing the Maven project. Changing that solved everything and the code generation tool included the @Override annotation even for interfaces.

Comment: nice find.. jdk 1.5 once again

Comment: I think you'd better increase the JDK to 1.6 in Maven.

Comment: It was due to the fact that Eclipse was using it's own maven, not the system one. Anyway it would be nice if you can point me to some page that details how to control that.

Comment: Thank you, you just saved my day! This is so lame. Java 6 is now out since, what, 5 years ?